# Dead link report in Election message

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, moderators, hyperlinks

On the page [2020 Moderator Election](https://music.stackexchange.com/election/2), the link [More information about the candidates](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#music.stackexchange) is not working.

Comment: There are no candidates yet. The nomination process just opened.

Comment: Currently nobody has nominated themselves for election - thus we have no candidates. This is not a bug

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. At this moment, there is one candidate, but the indicated link is still not working.

Comment: My sense is that some of these links are non-existent just because we haven't reached that stage of the election. The "more information" link will be available once we have a set list of candidates, and the "The candidates answer your questions" link will only be available once that thread has been created. In other words, the election page is a general hub for the election, but some of the links just aren't active yet.

Comment: @Karlo - you were correct. The link needed to be manually edited by staff. Thank you for highlighting this.